# Twitter profile link or username by profile image url

Tags: php, javascript, api, twitter

Is there a way of getting Twitter profile link or user name by their profile image url using Javascript or php? (e.g https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/3073162784/136eb71c2f5c3ae10b44578baca6c778.jpeg)

Answer (score 0):

While it is not automated, you could try a Google Image Search using that image. That's how I found out that profile image belongs to [pagliere](http://twitter.com/pagliere).